# Culture dependent numeric conversion not working

Tags: c#, culture

In Germany the number 9.81 (US) is represented as

> 9,81

What's wrong with the following conversion?

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
NumberStyles style = NumberStyles.Float ;//| NumberStyles.AllowThousands;

string str = "9,81";
double value = 0.0;

if (double.TryParse(str, style, culture, out value)) 
  Console.WriteLine("Result of conversion: " + value);
else 
  Console.WriteLine("Numeric conversion failed!");
```

> Numeric conversion failed!

BTW, thousands separator ('.') doesn't work either...

Comment: [Works on my machine](https://ideone.com/1CLsct). Have the regional settings been changed on your machine, so that the German display format uses a period (`.`) as decimal separator?

Comment: @CodeCaster: stupid me! ^^ Yeah I changed it because I open Excel sheets with US format so often. Thanks for pointing out!